# Does storing and retrieving data from memory is faster than doing the same from the DOM using data attributes and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Please note that I'm after processing hundreds and even thousands of elements at once (sometimes even all DOM elements what so ever), and not a single element where performance is that case would obviously have no meaning at all.

Is going

```
if( element.active ) {  }
```

faster than

```
if( jQuery('.element').attr('data-active') === 'true' ) { }
```

Same question for storing the active state, I.E:

```
element.active = true
```

And

```
jQuery('.element').attr('data-active', 'true');
```

---

If its not faster, why would i prefer to use the memory and not the DOM? if it is faster, why?

Comment: Yes it's faster.  Anything dealing with less method calls and more direct property access will be faster

Comment: The DOM is an *in-memory* representation, almost by definition. Not sure what you mean by trying to choose between the two. But of course using jQuery will be slower than not using it.

Comment: @cHao I was going to make this point IMO it's vital to start with this understanding

Comment: https://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-attr/34

Comment: The question reflects a lack of understanding of just how much work a jQuery constructor has to do.

Comment: @Andreas can you elaborate a bit about this test that you've linked to?

Comment: There isn't much to elaborate. You're asking "what is faster?" and the tests has test cases for every option you've asked for + `.data()`